# Let $P(x)$ be an open sentence. Is "$P(x)$ and not $P(x)$ proposition?

Tags: logic

Let P(x) be an open sentence. Is "P(x) and not P(x)" a proposition ? And another question. Is  " if n=2, then n is even" a proposition ? P.S. I don't know where link of teaching for writing symbol of maths is. Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: [The MathJax tutorial is here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: "P(x) and not P(x)" is an open sentence as well. Why shouldn't it be? It has the variable x. The same holds for "if n=2, then n is even".

Comment: @Crostul Yes, but whatever $x$ and $P$ are, $Px\land\neg Px$ will always be false.

Comment: Thank you. So " if n=2, then n is even" is a open sentence too, don't it?

Comment: @อาจารย์สมศักดิ์สอนคณิต What is your definition of open/closed sentences?

Comment: Open sentence is the sentence that we can't say it is true or not.

Comment: @อาจารย์สมศักดิ์สอนคณิต Then we have the same definition :) We can't decide whether $Px$ is true or not, without knowing what $x$ and $P$ are. However, we know that $Px\land\neg Px$ (that is, $Px$ and its negation at the same time) is always false. Thus $Px\land\neg Px$ is actually a _closed_ sentence.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I think that I understand it more than.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we seem to be dealing with first-order logic here, so I suppose you mean whether $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ is a *sentence*.

In usual terminology, we define a sentence to be a well-formed first-order formula with no free occurrence of variables, i.e. a closed formula. Thus, $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ is not a *sentence* in this sense.

Yes, "if $n=2$, then $n$ is even" can be regarded as proposition, particularly, a conditional one:

> $P \rightarrow Q$

where $P$ represents '$n=2$' and $Q$ stands for '$n$ is even'.

Comment: But we can see " n=2" and "n is even" are two open sentence that n is an variable, can't it?

Comment: @อาจารย์สมศักดิ์สอนคณิต To say that it is a proposition means it is a formula of the **propositional calculus**. Therefore, it cannot be a open sentence, since sentences are formulas of first-order (predicate) logic whose variables are free. The same sentence can be *formalized* in a **first-order language** too, and, when we do it, we usually take it to be something like $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n=2 \rightarrow n$ is even. (Which follows from the usual practice of mathematicians of assuming the universal quantifiers as implicit). This is no proper formalism, though.

Answer (score 0):

"P(x) and not P(x)" is an open sentence as well. Why shouldn't it be? It has the variable x."
  No because it is FALSE for all possible values of x.  This statement is a proposition.

"The same holds for "if n=2, then n is even"." 
n is NOT a variable here because it is equal to 2.  This statement is true and so is a proposition.

Demosthenes, a "proposition" is a statement that is either true or false (even if you do not know which)O.  An "open sentence" is a statement containing a variable which may be true or false depending on the value of the variable.

Comment: But we can see " n=2" and "n is even" are two open sentence that n is an variable, can't it?